# How to send Motion JPEG through internet to Windows phone over TCP

Tags: c#, http, tcp, mjpeg

I would like to send motion JPEG from my computer to the Windows Phone telephone with global ip `89.232.123.122`. How to establish a connection with that mobile phone and push the mjpeg through the connection?

Comment: Global IP 344.232.123.122 doesn't exist.

Comment: @Inspired That was example. I corrected it.

Comment: Please explain what part specifically you're having trouble with. Who is the initiating party, the phone or the server? Does the server know the phone's IP address? Can you connect to the phone from the server? Is an application listening on the phone? Do you know how to read a file from the server, and do you have a protocol to get the file to the phone? Do you know how to play back this video format on the phone?

Comment: @CodeCaster That is the question about.

Comment: So you want help on _everything_? That's too broad for SO.

Answer (score 1):

for sending multimedia (like motion JPEG) use UDP instead of TCP.

in the sender side use this code :

```
  UdpClient sendFrame = new UdpClient();
  // your image is img:
  Bitmap img = new Bitmap("pic.png");


  // always send image
  while (true)
                {
      MemoryStream memory_Stream = new MemoryStream();
      // convert bitmap to jpg
      SaveJPG100(img, memory_Stream);

      byte[] byte_Of_Frame = memory_Stream.ToArray();
     // send data on port 2000 on remote host
     sendFrame.Send(byte_Of_Frame, byte_Of_Frame.Length,"89.232.123.122",2000);

                }
```

// convert btm to jpg

```
public void SaveJPG100(Bitmap bmp, System.IO.Stream stream)
{

    EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
    encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);
    bmp.Save(stream, GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg), encoderParameters);
}

// generate jpg description
public ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
{

    ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

    foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
    {
        if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
        {
            return codec;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

on the receiver side use this code

```
            UdpClient receiveFrame = new UdpClient(2000);
            // recieve data from any ip address and any port
            IPEndPoint remote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.ANY, 0);

            while (true)
            {

                byte[] byte_Of_Frame = receiveFrame.Receive(ref remote);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byte_Of_Frame);

                pictureBox1.Image=(new Bitmap(ms));
            }
```

Comment: Great, thank you. Altough this is example of UDP usage not TCP, so there is no guarantee that the data will get to the mobile phone. I need to use TCP protocol to be sure that the connection is set between them(also there will be authorization).

Answer (score 0):

u must have web service and upload your picture to web service and save  it in server or in database but i suggest save it in server ...

in Web Service :

```
 [WebMethod]
    public string UploadFile(byte[] f, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(f);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream
               (System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/ArchiveImages/") +
               fileName, FileMode.Create);
            ms.WriteTo(fs);
            ms.Close();
            fs.Close();
            fs.Dispose();

            return "ok";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
```

and in client app :

```
private void UploadFile(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            ArchiveServiceObj.ArchiveServiceSoapClient srv = new ArchiveServiceObj.ArchiveServiceSoapClient();

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            picscannedimage.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();
            string sTmp = srv.UploadFile(pic, filename + ".jpg");
            MessageBox.Show("File Upload Status: " + sTmp, "File Upload");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Upload Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: By web service did you mean `class WebService`? Can you provide example please? My computer will be server, all the data are on `C:\Video\example.mjpeg`.